# cocoa: weird purple constraint for split view

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

If I add three split views as following image, the third split view, referred as splitView-3, will automatically generate a constraint for custom view in that split view, like Height(42) of customview1. As a result, I can't change the height of customview1 in Interface Builder.

why does Interface Builder automatically generate a purple constraint, like Height(43), for customview1?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It generates it because you manually sized the view to a specific height in its superview. Promote the constraint (in the size Utility Panel) to a user constraint and delete it. That should get you most if not all the way there (but I can't tell without seeing the rest of your constraint configuration).

Comment: Thank you, but what is meaning of "you manually sized the view to a specific height in its superview."? because I didn't add any constraint to my split view, I just dragged them from IB. I try to promote the constraint and delete it in size Utility Panel, but the result is the constraint turn blue after I promote it and then turn purple after I delete it. which constraint configuration does you need? I have updated my image.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua is right... but there is one little tidbit I think needs to be explained.

**Xcode needs constraints to determine position and size of ALL items**. The purple ones it sticks in because there aren't enough constraints to satisfy those needs without sticking in a few extra.

So, Xcode is sticking in a constraint for height, that means it has no way to determine the height from your existing constraints. You can define it by adding constraint so:

- the height is equal to the height of some other item
- by setting the bottom distance X points away from another item
- by setting the bottom position relative to it's superview
- or .... well, a lot more, but hopefully you get the idea

Once you add in a constraint which let's Xcode know the view's height, that purple one will either vanish or become blue so you can delete it and have it not come back.